# Uncaught Range Error Maximum call stack exceeded whilst trying to make variable from form input JS

Tags: javascript, html

As the title would suggest I keep getting that error when trying to test out a basic script which would "read" form inputs and make them variables to use later on.

HTML:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" 
   src="./js/lisearch.js"></script>
  <form name="search" action="" method="post">
      <h2>Include:</h2>
      <div id="formtitle" class="formdiv">
        <p> Current Job Title:</p><input id="jtitle" type="text" name="jobtitle" placeholder="Demand planner, Supply planner">
      </div>
      <div id="formcompany" class="formdiv">
        <p> Current Company:</p><input id="cmpy" type="text" name="company" placeholder="GSK OR Danone">
      </div>
      <div id="formkeywords" class="formdiv">
        <p> Keywords:</p><input id="kwrd" type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="(SAP OR JDE) AND FMCG">
      </div>
      <div id="formfirst" class="formdiv">
        <p> First Name:</p><input id="fname" type="text" name="first">
      </div>
      <div id="formlast" class="formdiv">
        <p> Last Name:</p><input id="lname" type="text" name="last">
      </div>
      <hr>
      <h2> Exclude:</h2>
      <div id="formnottitle" class="formdiv">
        <p> Current Job Title:</p><input id="njtitle" type="text" name="notjobtitle" placeholder="Manager OR Consultant">
      </div>
      <div id="formnotcompany" class="formdiv">
        <p> Current Company:</p><input id="ncmpy" type="text" name="notcompany" placeholder="Coke OR Pepsi">
      </div>
      <div id="formnotkeywords" class="formdiv">
        <p> Keywords:</p><input id="nkwrd" type="text" name="notkeywords" placeholder="Recruiter OR Recruitment">
      </div>
      <div id="submit" class="formdiv">
        <input type="button" value="Create Search" onclick="onclick()">
      </div>
      <div id="output" class="formdiv">
        <input type="text" name="output">
      </div>
    </form>
```

JS:

```
var company;
var jobtitle;
var keywords;
var fname;
var lname;
var notcompany;
var notjobtitle;
var notkeywords;
function onclick() {
  company = document.getElementById('cmpy').value;
  jobtitle = document.getElementById('jtitle').value;
  keywords = document.getElementById('kwrd').value;
  fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
  lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
  notcompany = document.getElementById('ncmpy').value;
  notjobtitle = document.getElementById('njtitle').value;
  notkeywords = document.getElementById('nkwrd').value;
  test();
}
function test() {
  alert(company + jobtitle + keywords + fname + lname + notcompany + notjobtitle + notkeywords);
}
```

As you can probably tell I am really new to all this but can't seem to figure this out, any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of message you get when doing recursive calls and get stuck somewhere in a cycle. in your case rename onclick() function to something else, that's it!
Here I made a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/D0PrOYrmz3puBdDiRcNN?p=preview)

```
function toto() {
  company = document.getElementById('cmpy').value;
  jobtitle = document.getElementById('jtitle').value;
  keywords = document.getElementById('kwrd').value;
  fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
  lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
  notcompany = document.getElementById('ncmpy').value;
  notjobtitle = document.getElementById('njtitle').value;
  notkeywords = document.getElementById('nkwrd').value;
  test();
}
function test() {
  alert(company + jobtitle + keywords + fname + lname + notcompany + notjobtitle + notkeywords);
}
```

and

```
<input type="button" value="Create Search" onclick="toto()">
```

Comment: Thanks that has done it! I should really read up on "reserved words"

Comment: I would do but as I have less than 15 rep it doesn't record my upvotes :(

Answer (score 0):

<s>put function test at the top of your js code so that onclick() knows what it is when the event handler is assigned.
Edit: Additional feedback:
The test function isn't even needed.  Just insert the alert code into the onclick function.
edit: Moving the script tags shouldn't actually have any effect. I am not sure what is going wrong here.</s>
Edit:solved it

```
<form name="search" action="" method="post">
      <h2>Include:</h2>
      <div id="formtitle" class="formdiv">
        <p> Current Job Title:</p><input id="jtitle" type="text" name="jobtitle" placeholder="Demand planner, Supply planner">
      </div>
      <div id="formcompany" class="formdiv">
        <p> Current Company:</p><input id="cmpy" type="text" name="company" placeholder="GSK OR Danone">
      </div>
      <div id="formkeywords" class="formdiv">
        <p> Keywords:</p><input id="kwrd" type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="(SAP OR JDE) AND FMCG">
      </div>
      <div id="formfirst" class="formdiv">
        <p> First Name:</p><input id="fname" type="text" name="first">
      </div>
      <div id="formlast" class="formdiv">
        <p> Last Name:</p><input id="lname" type="text" name="last">
      </div>
      <hr>
      <h2> Exclude:</h2>
      <div id="formnottitle" class="formdiv">
        <p> Current Job Title:</p><input id="njtitle" type="text" name="notjobtitle" placeholder="Manager OR Consultant">
      </div>
      <div id="formnotcompany" class="formdiv">
        <p> Current Company:</p><input id="ncmpy" type="text" name="notcompany" placeholder="Coke OR Pepsi">
      </div>
      <div id="formnotkeywords" class="formdiv">
        <p> Keywords:</p><input id="nkwrd" type="text" name="notkeywords" placeholder="Recruiter OR Recruitment">
      </div>
      <div id="submit" class="formdiv">
        <input type="button" id="onclick" value="Create Search"/>
      </div>
      <div id="output" class="formdiv">
        <input type="text" name="output"/>
      </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var company;
var jobtitle;
var keywords;
var fname;
var lname;
var notcompany;
var notjobtitle;
var notkeywords;
document.getElementById("onclick").onclick=function() {
  company = document.getElementById('cmpy').value;
  jobtitle = document.getElementById('jtitle').value;
  keywords = document.getElementById('kwrd').value;
  fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
  lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
  notcompany = document.getElementById('ncmpy').value;
  notjobtitle = document.getElementById('njtitle').value;
  notkeywords = document.getElementById('nkwrd').value;
  alert(company + jobtitle + keywords + fname + lname + notcompany + notjobtitle + notkeywords);
}
        </script>
```

Comment: That still gives the same error even with test function at the top